# How to for loop through titles of books in website

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm pretty new to Java and trying to learn how to crawl from a website. I'm crawling a top 100 bestselling books from Barnes & noble.

I managed myself to crawl the top 1 title from its web, but when I'm trying to make it into a for loop to crawl all the titles, I cannot do it. It all just gives out blank output.

```java
String url = "https://www.barnesandnoble.com/b/books/_/N-1fZ29Z8q8";
Document doc = null;
try {
    doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
} catch ( Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
// System.out.println(doc);
Element top100 = doc.select(".text").first();
System.out.println(top100.text());
Elements bookList = doc.select("ol.product-shelf-list product-list-view > li");
for(Element book : bookList) {
    Element titleElement = book.select(".row topX-row > div.product-info-view > div.product-shelf-title > .product-info-view").first();
    String title = titleElement.text();
    System.out.println(title);
}
// Element title = doc.select(".product-info-title").first();
// System.out.println(title.text());
```

The bottom two lines print the first book title 'The Great Awakening (10/15/2020)' with no problem, but in a for loop, I can't print any of the titles.

I noticed that titles are located like this:

```html
<ol class="product-shelf-list product-list-view">
   <li class="pb-s mt-m bd-bottom-disabled-gray record list-view-data">   // book 1
      <div class="row topX-row">
         <div class="product-info-view">
            <div class="product-shelf-title">
               <h3 class="product-info-title">
   <li class="pb-s mt-m bd-bottom-disabled-gray record list-view-data">   // book 2
      <div class="row topX-row">
         <div class="product-info-view">
            <div class="product-shelf-title">
               <h3 class="product-info-title">
```

and so on. I'm trying to use my loop to get to the h3 for every book.

I tried different ways to doc.select(....), ran with only .product-info-title in there move li here and there I don't know. I'm just lost with how this thing works. They all just gave me blank outputs besides my B&N Top 100: Book Bestsellers from printing out top100.